# replace two newlines to one in shell command line

Tags: perl, shell, replace, sed, newline

There are lot of questions about replacing multi-newlines to one newline but no one is working for me.
I have a file:

```
first line
second line MARKER

third line MARKER
other lines

many other lines
```

I need to replace two newlines (if they exist) after `MARKER` to one newline. A result file should be:

```
first line
second line MARKER
third line MARKER
other lines

many other lines
```

I tried `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/MARKER\n\n/MARKER\n/g'` Fail.
`sed` is useful for single line replacements but has problems with newlines. It can't find `\n\n`

I tried `perl -i -p -e 's/MARKER\n\n/MARKER\n/g'` Fail.
This solution looks closer, but it seems that regexp didn't reacts to `\n\n`.

Is it possible to replace `\n\n` only after `MARKER` and not to replace other `\n\n` in the file?
I am interested in one-line-solution, not scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were on the right track. In a multi-line program, you would load the entire file into a single scalar and run this substitution on it:

```
s/MARKER\n\n/MARKER\n/g
```

The trick to getting a one-liner to load a file into a multi-line string is to set `$/` in a `BEGIN` block. This code will get executed once, before the input is read.

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{$/=undef} s/MARKER\n\n/MARKER\n/g' input
```

Comment: Thank you! @ikegami post was earlier but your solution much clearer! It exactly what I asked.

Comment: @oluckyman, I intentionally avoided this answer as it needlessly loads the entire file in memory. But since you appear to prefer shorter answers, I've added an even terser solution to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your Perl solution doesn't work because you are search for lines that contain two newlines. There is no such thing. Here's one solution:

```
perl -ne'print if !$m || !/^$/; $m = /MARKER$/;' infile > outfile
```

Or in-place:

```
perl -i~ -ne'print if !$m || !/^$/; $m = /MARKER$/;' file
```

If you're ok with loading the entire file into memory, you can use

```
perl -0777pe's/MARKER\n\n/MARKER\n/g;' infile > outfile
```

or

```
perl -0777pe's/MARKER\n\K\n//g;' infile > outfile
```

As above, you can use `-i~` do edit in-place. Remove the `~` if you don't want to make a backup.

Comment: @oluckyman, It wasn't empty, it contained only the blank lines that were suppose to be removed. I had the condition inverted. Fixed.

Comment: @oluckyman, For each line, 1) Prints the current line if it's not preceded by a marker line (by checking $m) or if it's not blank. 2) Note in $m whether the current line is a marker line.

Comment: @oluckyman, The third version: 1) Tell Perl that the consider the whole file one line (`-0777`), then 2) for each line, 2A) replace every "\n" preceded by "MARKER\n" with nothing, and 2B) print out the line.

Answer (score 2):

awk:

```
kent$  cat a
first line
second line MARKER

third line MARKER
other lines

many other lines

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{RS="\x034"} {gsub(/MARKER\n\n/,"MARKER\n");printf $0}' a
first line
second line MARKER
third line MARKER
other lines

many other lines
```

Answer (score 0):

See [sed one liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This is especially true given the large number of unrelated one-liners in that link. I couldn't find one that addresses this specific question by searching the document for "newline" or "\n\n" which I'd expect to be mentioned by such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  marker { marker = 0; if (/^$/) next }
  /MARKER/ { marker = 1 }
  { print }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in very simple `sed`.

```
sed '/MARKER$/{n;/./!d}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/MARKER/,//{//!d}'
```

Explanation:

Deletes all lines between `MARKER`'s preserving the `MARKER` lines.

Or:

```
sed '/MARKER/{n;N;//D}'
```

Explanation:

Read the next line after `MARKER`, then append the line after that. Delete the previous line if the current line is a `MARKER` line.