# sed: Delete blank lines following line ending with a marker

Tags: shell, sed

How do I do this using ***`sed`***?

```
    Input:                         Expected output:
    1               |              1
    2 MARKER        |              2 MARKER
                    |              3 MARKER
                    |              4
                    |              
                    |              5 MARKER
                    |              6
                    |              
    3 MARKER        |              
                    |              7 MARKER
    4               |              8
                    |              9
    5 MARKER        |                      
    6               |               
                    |              
                    |              
    7 MARKER        |                      
                    |              
    8               |               
    9               |
```

First I tried this: It doesn't work coz "# niether t or b work because d causes the script to break."

```
/MARKER$/ {
#   i -- Line with MARKER
:my_branch
#   i -- in branch
    # write current patt space to output and read next line to pattern space
    n
    # if non blank goto EO script
    /^$/! b
    # if blank line delete it
    /^$/ d
    # loop back for more blank lines.
    t my_branch
    # niether t or b work because d causes the script to break.
    b my_branch
}
```

then I tried this, which almost works :((( -- it doesn't remove the line between 3 and 4, which I think is because 3 is consumed during the processing of 2 and thus it's marker is missed.

```
/MARKER$/ {
#       i -- Line with MARKER
:my_branch
#   i -- in branch
    N
    s/MARKER\n/MARKER/
    t my_branch
    # I added the following but it doesn't help..
    /MARKER$/ b my_branch
}
```

there 4-5 other versions I tried, but none worked.

I did all this because I was trying to answer this question: [replace two newlines to one in shell command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535587/replace-two-newlines-to-one-in-shell-command-line), so I started learning sed from http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt and http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

IOW I know there are solutions using awk, perl etc but I just wanted to learn using sed.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the transformation you are trying to create. why are there still blank lines remaining in your output (Just for learning?) Can you tell us the rules you are trying to implement? Otherwise very nice posting. thanks for including what you have already read and are aware of! Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the commend there. Perhaps you missed to include the title in the whole question. :) If you notice, the blank line preceded by lines ending with "MARKER" are deleted. Other blank lines are not supposed to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below, I think it is what you want: (it ran on my linux box with gnu sed)

```
kent$  cat t
1         
2 MARKER  






3 MARKER  

4         

5 MARKER  
6         


7 MARKER  

8         
9         

kent$  sed -r ':a;N;s/(.*MARKER)\s+(\n.*)/\1\2/;ba;' t
1         
2 MARKER
3 MARKER
4         

5 MARKER
6         


7 MARKER
8         
9
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this work for large files? It looks like it would load/process the whole file in pattern space before writing out anything. Accepted as answer anyway, as it answers my question.

Comment: you can generate a "huge" file, and give it a try. ;)